# How to embed WKWebView inside custom UIView properly?

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

In my project I have a view controller where i want to show WKWebView embedded inside another UIView titled viewForEmbeddingWebView that i've created in a storyboard (grey on the picture).

[image: grey view titled viewForEmbeddingWebView in my View controller]

I've implemented this logic in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate  {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var viewForEmbeddingWebView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView(frame: viewForEmbeddingWebView.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration() )
        self.viewForEmbeddingWebView.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }

}
```

After build and running in Simulator I see the following:
[image: after running my code]

It shows WKWebView but the bounds look wrong (first: it does not fit the viewForEmbeddingWebView's bounds and second: there is a white gap at the top). I've read that I must use WKWebView on the apple's site https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview but their example is not my situation, because they only showing how to deal in the situation with loading WKWebView in the whole View of ViewController. But I need it to be embedded into another view because i will also need another ui later around this WKWebView. Before WKWebView there was WebView but since iOS 8 appeared we must use WKWebView. Please help, because i've checked lot of materials but have not find the answer working great with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 with iOS 10.2.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to initialize `WKWebView` like this (Swift 3.0):

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: viewForEmbeddingWebView.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.viewForEmbeddingWebView.addSubview(webView)
```

Comment: it is working but problem not solved full. In your solution i still see a white gap at the top of WKWebView. How to hide it? It is a white scrollView behind WKWebView as it seems to me. How to make WKWebView to fit it without this white gap? P.S. In your solution i also don't see  webView.uiDelegate = self . Will I need it or not to make WKWebView work properly?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we can see how it looks after making that change? Have you checked your app with Xcode's view hierarchy debugger? (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: solved blank space with adding :  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false to viewDidLoad, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

WKWebView Swift 5 or Custom WKWebView(Webview deprecated)
Please follow below the Apple link for WKWebView -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

If you want to add WKWebView in a custom view. Please follow the Code.

```
 import WebKit 

 class OpenControllerURL: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate , WKUIDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var CustomView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview"!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.CustomView.frame)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] //It assigns Custom View height and width
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    
    webView.load(request)
    self.CustomView.addSubview(webView)
}
```

#Happy Coding!!!